# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS on Apache VirtualHost server not working

Tags: apache, ssl, https, server, ip

My website is connecting through HTTP and redirecting to the HTTPS VirtualHost but there it ends.

I wouldn't post if I hadn't searched for hours without result. Please see the following:

[Trying to connect through port 443 (With VirtualHost setup and Port Info)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enu7G.png)

My ports.conf file is the following:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

[And this is my router setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl9Y6.png)

yes, ssl is enabled through apache and running with ssl_mod being enabled.

All posts lead me to different types of configs in my VirtualHost for port 80, but I tried them all.

Is there anything I missed?

**EDIT**

*UFW config*

sudo ufw status

```
To              Action    From
--              ------    ----
WWW Full        ALLOW     Anywhere
443/tcp         ALLOW     Anywhere
WWW Full (v6)   ALLOW     Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)    ALLOW     Anywhere
```

*Further description of WWW Full*

sudo nano /etc/ufw/applications.d/ufw-webserver

```
...
[WWW Full]
title=Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
description=Web Server (HTTP,HTTPS)
ports=80,443/tcp
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The redirect to HTTPS can be enabled in the Virtual Host file for port 80. If you would like to force HTTPS for all web pages, you can use the following set of directives, after running `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and
`sudo a2enmod ssl`:

to redirect everything to https://yourdomain.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourdomain.com
Redirect permanent / https://yourdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
SSLEngine On
...
</VirtualHost>
```

to redirect everything to https://www.yourdomain.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.yourdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
SSLEngine On
...
</VirtualHost>
```

to redirect a specific directory (/secure in our case):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
Redirect permanent /secure https://yourdomain.com/secure
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
SSLEngine On
...
</VirtualHost>
```

You can read more about other approaches including `.htaccess` [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/apache-redirect-to-https/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am currently running a redirect through different configuration files and keeping the virtual hosts separate by enabling them both. Do you suggest just inserting SSLEngine On in my VH for 443, or should I merge them also and a2dissite the other config?

Comment: Just adding it to your virtual hosts will be enough, I guess

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7 Hope this helps

Comment: I tried adding and merging but the same result still applies. I have installed my certificate through Letsencrypt (certbot) and it is verified by SSL Checker... The issue lies only in the redirect as the top of the first image shows, and I really don't see an issue. I use UFW with both ports allowed, even allowing specifically for 433...

Comment: what does `sudo ufw status` show on your console?

Comment: Posted under Edit!

Comment: So what's your issue now? The redirection isn't working yet?

Comment: Yes, same issue as before. Im testing with wget and HTTP reponse is 302 found -> redirecting to (https://)website.com, and there it retries until it times out...

Comment: Then your redirection seems working, you'd better check SSL config for https://your_domain. Can you access your site with https in the browser?

Comment: I cannot... tried wget after using https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/ and finding out my redirect wasn't working... wget gave me info on HTTP redirect going on but HTTPS/SSL being the issue. Certifications however works great, and the website I linked also tells me that certs are allright. So that leaves HTTPS/Apache or something I haven't found yet

Comment: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/apache-redirect-to-https/ Please check these steps

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Hi again! I found an issue. My website is accessible with www.example.com:80

This makes 0 sense to me. Is it router settings?

Comment: When you access 80 port, is it HTTP or https?

Comment: It's http, but gets redirected to https:// mydomain.com

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have finally, after like 5 days, figured out the issue. I am able to connect to my website through (https://)www.website.com if i enter exactly that. If I however enter www.website.com or website.com I am not able to establish a connection. This is either because my SSL certificate is wrongly configured, or because of a redirect setting. I am new to this but will leave the issue alone unless someone knows the answer...

Comment: `unless someone knows the answer` -- I am struggling with this same problem today and yesterday and would benefit from knowing the answer.